# Removing input autocomplete, in javascript and html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form and add text style in the input, if user click the input, the text shrink and goes up. It's working good till google autocomplete remember username and password, the autocomplete is messing the style.

So far I tried using `autocomplete="off"`, but doesn't work:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" size="15" name="login" id="login" required/>
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" size="15" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required/>
```

Also I tried using js, but doesn't work as well:

```
function connectForm() {
    document.querySelector(".totalconnect_form").autocomplete = "off";
}

connectForm();
```

Is there a way to solve this? to remove the autocomplete?
Or if not possible, I can use js using condition, but I'm not sure how to target the autocomplete in js, any advice will be helpful, thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If a user agrees that the browser can populate forms, `autocomplete="off"` has no effect on username and password fields. You can use `autocomplete="new-password"` to the password <input> if you expect different users on the same computer.

Comment: you can try `autocomplete="anyrandomstring"` also `autocomplete="nope"` seems to work; as Chrome will ignore the `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: @BenHulan, tried your way, but unfortunatelly doesn't work

Comment: @Hasan Patel, tried your way, but unfortunatelly doesn't work

Comment: Hmm. This works for me. Can you make sure there are no login/password values stored in localStorage or sessionStorage, clear the cache and try again?